# WPF - MVVM - Combobox UserControl + ComboboxItem CustomControl

Tags: xaml, mvvm, binding, datacontext

I am struggling to create a binding from a View + ViewModel to a Custom ComboboxItem. I am not sure it should work, I already had implemented complex UserControls and had to deal with setting the DataContext properly to make it work with MVVM, but this specific scenario doesn't work at all.

**What I am trying to do:**

Create a user control based on a Combobox. It will have Combobox behavior but it is customized. The combobox collapsed will show only a button without the Path, and when expanded (showing the dropdown list of combobox items), it will show more buttons customized.
This UserControl must work with MVVM (which is not working right now). If i set the ComboboxItem's content on the View hard coded they show correctly, but if I try to do a binding with viewmodel, it fails:

> System.Windows.Data Error: 40 : BindingExpression path error: 'MessageName' property not found on 'object' ''MultiButtonControl' (Name='')'. BindingExpression:Path=MessageName; DataItem='MultiButtonControl' (Name=''); target element is 'TestComboBoxItem' (Name=''); target property is 'Content' (type 'Object')

I created :

- A usercontrol MultiButtonControl containing a grid and a combobox with a specific style and a List called Children in the code behind (dependency property). I create a binding from the combobox on xaml with the Children property.
- A custom control TestComboBoxItem.cs which extends from ComboBoxItem. And I created on Generic.xaml a style for that type.

**DataContext:**

I set the DataContext of the UserControl "MultiButtonControl.xaml" on the parent element -> Grid element as:

```
<Grid DataContext="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type UserControl}}}">
```

**Currently working:**

Right now the layout works fine. I can use my UserControl in the View, add the Children too. But the problem is the binding. I believe the problem is the DataContext. Because when I try to bind a property from ComboboxItem (TestComboBoxItem custom control) it fails, and if I set it hardcoded it works.

Let me give you the code:

**View.xaml**

```
<Window x:Class="Test2Manager.message.ModalMessageInsert"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Test2Manager.message"
    xmlns:controls="clr-namespace:CSIncludes.controls;assembly=CSIncludes"
    xmlns:wpf="clr-namespace:CSIncludes.wpf;assembly=CSIncludes"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    WindowStyle="None"
    AllowsTransparency="True"
    WindowStartupLocation="CenterOwner" 
    WindowState="Maximized"
    Background="#33000000"
    Title="ModelMessageInsert"
    Name="ModalWindow">
<Window.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary Source="/CSIncludes;component/Themes/Generic.xaml"/>
</Window.Resources>
<Grid Width="600" Height="400" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Background="Gray">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="30"></RowDefinition>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"></RowDefinition>
        <RowDefinition Height="30"></RowDefinition>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <TextBlock Grid.Row="0"></TextBlock>
    <Grid Grid.Row="1" Margin="5">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="30"></RowDefinition>
            <RowDefinition Height="30"></RowDefinition>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"></RowDefinition>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"></ColumnDefinition>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="10"></ColumnDefinition>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"></ColumnDefinition>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <TextBlock Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" VerticalAlignment="Center">Name:</TextBlock>
        <TextBox Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="2" VerticalAlignment="Center" Text="{Binding MessageName, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}">
            <TextBox.Effect>
                <DropShadowEffect Color="Yellow" Direction="270" ShadowDepth="2" Opacity="1" BlurRadius="2"></DropShadowEffect>
            </TextBox.Effect>

        </TextBox>
        <!--<controls:AudioControl Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="2" RecordingMode="False" ReproduceAudioPath="C:\Fabio\Musicas\05 - On The Turning Away.mp3"></controls:AudioControl>-->
        <controls:MultiButtonControl Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="2" Width="170" ParentButtonText="{Binding MessageName}" ParentButtonImage="/CSIncludes;component/images/audio_play.png">
            <controls:MultiButtonControl.Children>
                <!--Command2="{Binding TestCommand}"-->
                <wpf:TestComboBoxItem Content="{Binding MessageName}"></wpf:TestComboBoxItem>
                <wpf:TestComboBoxItem Content="Fabio 2"></wpf:TestComboBoxItem>
                <wpf:TestComboBoxItem>Fabio 3</wpf:TestComboBoxItem>
            </controls:MultiButtonControl.Children>
        </controls:MultiButtonControl>
        <!--<ComboBox Style="{StaticResource CustomCombobox}">
            <ComboBoxItem>Item1</ComboBoxItem>
            <ComboBoxItem>Item2</ComboBoxItem>
            <ComboBoxItem>Item3</ComboBoxItem>
            <ComboBoxItem>Item4</ComboBoxItem>
            <ComboBoxItem>Item5</ComboBoxItem>
        </ComboBox>-->
    </Grid>
    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Grid.Row="2" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Margin="5">
        <Button Width="65" Command="{Binding SaveCommand}" CommandParameter="{Binding ElementName=ModalWindow}">Save</Button>
        <Button Width="65" Command="{Binding CancelCommand}" CommandParameter="{Binding ElementName=ModalWindow}" Margin="5,0,0,0">Cancel</Button>
    </StackPanel>
</Grid>
```

**View - code-behind setting DataContext to ViewModel**

```
    using Arbeit.wpf;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Shapes;

namespace Test2Manager.message
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for ModelMessageInsert.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class ModalMessageInsert : Window
    {
        ViewModelModalMessageInsert vm;
        public ModalMessageInsert(Test2Entities Context, Action UpdateList)
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            vm = new ViewModelModalMessageInsert(Context, UpdateList);
            DataContext = vm;
        }
    }
}
```

**ViewModel**

```
    using CSIncludes.wpf;
using Test2EF;
using Test2Manager.database;
using Test2Manager.manager;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Input;

namespace Test2Manager.message
{
    class ViewModelModalMessageInsert
    {
        private Test2Entities Context;
        private MessageDAL MessageDAL;
        private Action UpdateList;
        private ModelMessage Model;

        public ViewModelModalMessageInsert(Test2Entities Context, Action UpdateList)
        {
            this.Context = Context;
            this.UpdateList = UpdateList;
            MessageDAL = new MessageDAL(Context);
            Model = new ModelMessage();
            Model.ClientId = LoggedManager.ClientId;

            MessageName = "Teste";
        }

        public string MessageName
        {
            get { return Model.Name; }
            set
            {
                Model.Name = value;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**MultiButtonControl.xaml**

```
<UserControl x:Class="CSIncludes.controls.MultiButtonControl"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
         xmlns:local="clr-namespace:CSIncludes.controls"
         xmlns:wpf="clr-namespace:CSIncludes.wpf"
         mc:Ignorable="d" 
         d:DesignHeight="55" d:DesignWidth="300">
<UserControl.Resources>
    <!--<ControlTemplate x:Key="ComboBoxToggleButton" TargetType="{x:Type ToggleButton}">
        <Grid>
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition />
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <Border
              x:Name="Border" 
              CornerRadius="0"
              Background="#FF3F3F3F"
              BorderBrush="#FF97A0A5"
              BorderThickness="1" />
        </Grid>
    </ControlTemplate>-->

    <ControlTemplate x:Key="ComboBoxTextBox" TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}">
        <Border x:Name="PART_ContentHost" Focusable="False" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" />
    </ControlTemplate>

    <Style x:Key="CustomCombobox" TargetType="{x:Type ComboBox}">
        <Setter Property="SnapsToDevicePixels" Value="true"/>
        <Setter Property="OverridesDefaultStyle" Value="true"/>
        <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility" Value="Auto"/>
        <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility" Value="Auto"/>
        <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll" Value="true"/>
        <Setter Property="MinWidth" Value="120"/>
        <Setter Property="MinHeight" Value="30"/>
        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="White"/>
        <!--<Setter Property="DataContext" Value="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type UserControl}}}"></Setter>-->
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ComboBox}">
                    <Grid>
                        <!--Template="{StaticResource ComboBoxToggleButton}"-->
                        <ToggleButton
                            VerticalAlignment="Center"
                            Height="{Binding ParentButtonHeight}" 
                            Name="ToggleButton" 
                            Focusable="false"
                            IsChecked="{Binding Path=IsDropDownOpen,Mode=TwoWay,RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}"
                            ClickMode="Press">

                            <ToggleButton.Style>
                                <Style TargetType="{x:Type ToggleButton}">
                                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="#5F1E78"></Setter>
                                    <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="#5F1E78"></Setter>
                                    <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="1"></Setter>
                                    <Setter Property="Template">
                                        <Setter.Value>
                                            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ToggleButton}">
                                                <Border BorderBrush="#FF97A0A5" BorderThickness="1" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Width="{TemplateBinding ActualWidth}">
                                                    <Grid Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Width="{TemplateBinding ActualWidth}">
                                                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                                            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"></ColumnDefinition>
                                                            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"></ColumnDefinition>
                                                            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"></ColumnDefinition>
                                                            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"></ColumnDefinition>
                                                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                                        <TextBlock Grid.Column="1" Margin="0,0,8,0" Foreground="White" Name="Text" Text="{Binding ParentButtonText}" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                                                        <Image Grid.Column="2" Name="Image" Width="16" Height="16" Source="{Binding ParentButtonImage}" />
                                                    </Grid>
                                                    <!--<Grid>
                                                        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                                            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                                                        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                                            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                                                            <ColumnDefinition Width="16" />
                                                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                                        <TextBlock Margin="10" Foreground="White" Grid.Column="0" Name="Text" Text="{Binding ParentButtonText}" HorizontalAlignment="Center" />
                                                        <Image Grid.Column="1" Name="Image" Source="{Binding ParentButtonImage}" />
                                                    </Grid>-->
                                                </Border>
                                                <!--<ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                                                    <Trigger Property="IsChecked" Value="True">
                                                        <Setter TargetName="Text" Property="Foreground" Value="White" />
                                                    </Trigger>
                                                </ControlTemplate.Triggers>-->
                                            </ControlTemplate>
                                        </Setter.Value>
                                    </Setter>
                                </Style>
                            </ToggleButton.Style>
                        </ToggleButton>
                        <!--<ToggleButton Content="aaa"
                            Name="ToggleButton" 
                            Template="{StaticResource ComboBoxToggleButton}" 
                            Grid.Column="2" 
                            Focusable="false"
                            IsChecked="{Binding Path=IsDropDownOpen,Mode=TwoWay,RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}"
                            ClickMode="Press">
                        </ToggleButton>-->
                        <TextBox x:Name="PART_EditableTextBox" Style="{x:Null}" Height="{Binding ParentButtonHeight}" Template="{StaticResource ComboBoxTextBox}"  HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
                                VerticalAlignment="Center" Focusable="True" Background="White" Foreground="Black" Visibility="Hidden" IsReadOnly="{TemplateBinding IsReadOnly}"/>
                        <Popup Name="Popup" Placement="Top" PlacementTarget="{Binding ElementName=PART_EditableTextBox}" IsOpen="{TemplateBinding IsDropDownOpen}" AllowsTransparency="True"  Focusable="False" PopupAnimation="Slide">
                            <Grid Name="DropDown" SnapsToDevicePixels="True" MinWidth="{TemplateBinding ActualWidth}" Width="{TemplateBinding ActualWidth}" MaxHeight="{TemplateBinding MaxDropDownHeight}" Height="{TemplateBinding ActualHeight}">
                                <Border  x:Name="DropDownBorder" Background="White" BorderThickness="1" BorderBrush="#888888"/>
                                <ScrollViewer Margin="0,0,0,0" SnapsToDevicePixels="True">
                                    <StackPanel IsItemsHost="True" KeyboardNavigation.DirectionalNavigation="Contained" />
                                </ScrollViewer>
                            </Grid>
                        </Popup>
                    </Grid>
                    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                        <Trigger Property="HasItems" Value="false">
                            <Setter TargetName="DropDownBorder" Property="MinHeight" Value="95"/>
                        </Trigger>
                        <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="false">
                            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="#888888"/>
                        </Trigger>
                        <Trigger Property="IsGrouping" Value="true">
                            <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll" Value="false"/>
                        </Trigger>
                        <Trigger SourceName="Popup" Property="Popup.AllowsTransparency" Value="true">
                            <Setter TargetName="DropDownBorder" Property="CornerRadius" Value="0"/>
                            <Setter TargetName="DropDownBorder" Property="Margin" Value="0,0,0,0"/>
                        </Trigger>
                        <Trigger Property="IsEditable"  Value="true">
                            <Setter Property="IsTabStop" Value="false"/>
                            <Setter TargetName="PART_EditableTextBox" Property="Visibility" Value="Visible"/>
                            <!--<Setter TargetName="ContentSite" Property="Visibility" Value="Hidden"/>-->
                        </Trigger>
                    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>

</UserControl.Resources>

<Grid DataContext="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type UserControl}}}">
    <ComboBox Style="{StaticResource CustomCombobox}" Focusable="False" x:Name="ComboBox" ItemsSource="{Binding Children}">
    </ComboBox>
</Grid>
```

**MultiButtonControl.xaml.cs**

```
    using CSIncludes.wpf;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Navigation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;

namespace CSIncludes.controls
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MultiButtonControl.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MultiButtonControl : UserControl
    {
        public MultiButtonControl()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            this.Loaded += UserControl_Loaded;
            Children = new List<TestComboBoxItem>();
        }

        public static readonly DependencyProperty ParentButtonTextProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
        "ParentButtonText",
        typeof(string),
        typeof(MultiButtonControl));

        public static readonly DependencyProperty ParentButtonImageProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
        "ParentButtonImage",
        typeof(ImageSource),
        typeof(AudioControl),
        new UIPropertyMetadata(null));

        public static readonly DependencyProperty ParentButtonHeightProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
        "ParentButtonHeight",
        typeof(double),
        typeof(MultiButtonControl));

        public static readonly DependencyProperty ChildButtonHeightProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
                "ChildButtonHeight",
                typeof(double),
                typeof(MultiButtonControl));

        public static readonly DependencyProperty ChildrenProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
                "Children",
                typeof(List<TestComboBoxItem>),
                typeof(MultiButtonControl));

        public string ParentButtonText
        {
            get { return (string)GetValue(ParentButtonTextProperty); }
            set { SetValue(ParentButtonTextProperty, value); }
        }

        public ImageSource ParentButtonImage
        {
            get { return (ImageSource)GetValue(ParentButtonImageProperty); }
            set { SetValue(ParentButtonImageProperty, value); }
        }

        public double ParentButtonHeight
        {
            get { return (double)GetValue(ParentButtonHeightProperty); }
            set { SetValue(ParentButtonHeightProperty, value); }
        }

        public double ChildButtonHeight
        {
            get { return (double)GetValue(ChildButtonHeightProperty); }
            set { SetValue(ChildButtonHeightProperty, value); }
        }

        public List<TestComboBoxItem> Children
        {
            get { return (List<TestComboBoxItem>)GetValue(ChildrenProperty); }
            set { SetValue(ChildrenProperty, value); }
        }

        void UserControl_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (ParentButtonHeight == 0)
                ParentButtonHeight = 35;

            if (ChildButtonHeight == 0)
                ChildButtonHeight = 25;

            ComboBox.MaxDropDownHeight = ComboBox.Items.Count * ChildButtonHeight;
        }

    }
}
```

**Generic.xaml**

```
    <Style x:Key="{x:Type wpf:TestComboBoxItem}" TargetType="{x:Type wpf:TestComboBoxItem}">
        <Setter Property="ComboBoxItem.SnapsToDevicePixels" Value="true"/>
        <Setter Property="ComboBoxItem.Foreground" Value="Black"/>
        <Setter Property="ComboBoxItem.OverridesDefaultStyle" Value="true"/>
        <Setter Property="ComboBoxItem.Height" Value="{Binding ChildButtonHeight}"/>
        <Setter Property="ComboBoxItem.VerticalAlignment" Value="Center"/>
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type local:TestComboBoxItem}">
                    <Border Name="Border"  Padding="5" SnapsToDevicePixels="true">
                        <ContentPresenter />
                    </Border>

                    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                        <Trigger Property="IsHighlighted" Value="true">
                            <Setter TargetName="Border" Property="Background" Value="#7E59F2"/>
                            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="White"/>
                        </Trigger>
                        <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="false">
                            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="#888888"/>
                        </Trigger>
                    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
```

**TestComboBoxItem.cs**

```
    using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Input;

namespace CSIncludes.wpf
{
    public class TestComboBoxItem : ComboBoxItem
    {
        static TestComboBoxItem()
        {
            DefaultStyleKeyProperty.OverrideMetadata(typeof(TestComboBoxItem), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(typeof(ComboBoxItem)));
        }

        public static DependencyProperty CommandParameter2Property =
        DependencyProperty.Register("CommandParameter2", typeof(object), typeof(TestComboBoxItem));

        public static DependencyProperty Command2Property =
            DependencyProperty.Register("Command2", typeof(ICommand), typeof(TestComboBoxItem));

        public static DependencyProperty ItemTextProperty =
                    DependencyProperty.Register("ItemText", typeof(string), typeof(TestComboBoxItem));

        public ICommand Command2
        {
            get { return (ICommand)GetValue(Command2Property); }
            set { SetValue(Command2Property, value); }
        }

        public object CommandParameter2
        {
            get { return GetValue(CommandParameter2Property); }
            set { SetValue(CommandParameter2Property, value); }
        }

        public string ItemText
        {
            get { return (string)GetValue(ItemTextProperty); }
            set { SetValue(ItemTextProperty, value); }
        }
    }
}
```

***Do you have any clue on how to fix that TestComboBoxItem bindings ? How would you do to make it work? After binding the Content, I will need to create bindings with ICommand too.***

Comment: I fixed the problem but I am sure it is not the correct way to do it. I injected the view model instance in the MultiButtonControl and I set the DataContext of the TestComboBoxItem to bind with that instance.